# how to rename index while getting a snapshot usuing rename pattern?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

i want to get a snapshot from repository, but instead log-events-2022.01.01 - events-2022.01.01. Can it possible replace 'log-' ?

```
POST _snapshot/snapshots/1/_restore
{
  "indices": "log-events-2022.01.01",
  "rename_pattern": "(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "events_$1"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Update the regex, to mach the part you want to keep.

## Solution

```json
POST _snapshot/snapshots/1/_restore
{
  "indices": "log-events-2022.01.01",
  "rename_pattern": "log-(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "$1"

}
```